# Question about who the subject is: 君が僕と結婚してくれたら、残りの人生ずっといい気分ですごせると思うよ

Tags: subjects

In the sentence:

> 君が僕と結婚してくれたら、残りの人生ずっといい気分ですごせると思うよ。

Who is the person who will be able to live their whole life feeling good? Is it 君 or 僕?

Comment: If it is necessary to tell which specific spouse will be happy, maybe they should not get married ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subject of the last half is ambiguous. It should depend on the surrounding context.

> 君と出会うまで、僕の人生はつまらないものだったんだ。でも、君と出会って僕は変わった。君が僕と結婚してくれたら、残りの人生ずっといい気分ですごせると思うよ。
>   → He is talking about 僕, and the subject of the last part is clearly 僕

> 君が結婚に興味がないことは知っている。でも君の20年後の人生についても考えて欲しい。君が僕と結婚してくれたら、残りの人生ずっといい気分ですごせると思うよ。
>   → He is talking about 君, and the subject of the last part is clearly 君

If there is absolutely no context, perhaps it's safest to assume the subject is "we".